# Can't solve "Could not build module "UIKit"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

On the way to develop iOS app in Objective-C and writing some code, Suddenly the error "Could not build module "UIKit" appeared.

[image: The error]
Opening the other Xcode project, same error caused.

(Xcode version is 7.3)

I have done them

・Clean（Cmd + K)

・Clean Build Folder

・Delete DerivedData

・Remove and add UIKit.framework

・Set the "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework modules" setting to YES

How can I solve it?

Comment: How does your code look like? And since you're using Objective-C, aren't you suppose to use AVFoundation or CoCoa instead of UIKit?

Comment: go to UIColor.h file and undo any changes made by you.Then cmd+s the file.I think you have accidently made some changes in the file.

Comment: I didn't change anything in UIColor.h. And I tried to uninstall & reinstall Xcode8, I could solve it. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Thank you so much, reinstall again Xcode 8 solved my UIKit errors too.

Comment: Just a tip: This occurred when I accidentally typed something in `UICollectionView.h`, replacing the particular file physically inside sdk folder with another fresh copy of this header from my friend's sdk solved this. You could also replace the entire sdk folder. This will save you from re-installing.

Comment: uninstall your Xcode and install again new Xcode

Comment: Reinstalling Xcode as per @pratikvarsani comment worked for me.  I did a comparison with the old install and in my case I had changes in UIApplication.h (file empty) which was breaking the build.

Answer (score 1):

The command `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*` to clear cache thoroghly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import #import  in every class where you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating some demo project and check if same error coming in new project? 
and if the error remain same then you will need to uninstall the Xcode and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting **Framework Search Paths** miscorrect causes the same error. Check your **Framework Search Paths** and be sure it's setup correctly.

Answer (score -1):

try To import `UIKit` in `UIColor.h` class and other classes where it require, in my case i have solved with this single line.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

if you still face issue so please let me know.

Comment: `UIColor.h` theres already `#import <UIKit/UIKitDefines.h>` imported. No need for `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`